# jQuery, Internet Explorer 9 gets wrong opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) library, This is my code:

#### CSS:

```
.card{
    hight: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="card"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".card").hover(function () {
    alert($(this).css("opacity"))
});
```

The opacity option is working for every browser (the box is has transparency), but
Chrome, Firefox and Safari are showing me a popup with value "0.20000002345". ***Only*** Internet Explorer 9 is showing "1".

Comment: Works for me in IE9 here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nZVFy/.  Note, you have `hight` spelled wrong in your CSS.   It does not work in versions of IE before IE9 because they don't know the CSS `opacity` word.  They use a filter to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I would be checking for other errors in ie that would stop that code form executing correctly. @jfriend00's example also works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS for opacity in IE (version <9)

`filter:alpha(opacity=20);`

jQuery for it:

```
$(".card").hover(function () {
    alert($(this).css("opacity"));
    var filter = $(this).css('filter');
    if (filter) {
        filter = parseInt( filter.replace(')','').replace('alpha(opacity=','') ) / 100; }

        alert(filter);
});​
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3U5u/1/)

Comment: Why are you using `css("filter")` ? I think, the `.css("opacity")` will work across browsers. After all its jQuery.

Comment: `opacity` doesn't work in IE, the IE equivalent is `filter:alpha(opacity=100)` where 100 is a value between 0-100... so `opacity:0.2;` == `filter:alpha(opacity=20);`

Comment: But, the OP's question is about IE9 and IE9 supports `opacity` so this answer has nothing to do with IE9.   Per my jsFiddle, this OP's code works in IE9.  This answer would apply to earlier versions of IE, but that is not what the OP asked about.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I think the `height` value spelled wrong threw him off... But my code applies to other versions of IE! :)

Comment: This site is about specific answers to specific questions.  Typically, you do not get points for an irrelevant answer no matter how helpful it might be for other situations.

Answer (score 5):

While using the `alpha filter` would fix the problem - it should't be required in IE9... Unless if IE9 were viewing the page in Compatibility Mode (therefore acting like an old version of IE).

If the OP were viewing the page as an Local Intranet Zone site, then compatibility mode is the default viewing mode in IE9 (as opposed to the Internet Zone), and as a result `css opacity` wouldn't work.

In IE9, go to: Page -> Compatibility View Settings -> uncheck 'Display Intranet sites in compatibility view' to turn that off.

A mix up with security zones and compatibility mode would explain why the OP was having problems, and why anyone viewing the above-linked test page on the public internet would see it properly.